# Matrix switch module for electronics testing - what uses?

Tags: test, matrix

I'm doing a presentation about NI PXI and such test equipment for school.

And I am explaining what the multiplexer and matrix modules can be used for.

The multiplexer is simple: Connect, for example, all voltage measurement points to the multiplexer inputs, and a DMM to the output, and cycle through them in order and acquire measurements.

But what exactly is the matrix used for? I can't figure out what the advantage of this one is.

Page 13 here shows a diagram etc: [enter link description here](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5989-1437EN.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplexer isn't enough if, for example, you would like to measure the voltage with one and the frequency with another instrument at several points. Another example would be to measure the voltage at different points under various loads. Then you have to connect the DMM AND one of several loads to various points.

Generally speaking you can run more complex mesurement tasks unattended over a long time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the advantage now. I also found some info on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_test_switching#Switch_System_Topology